# Image size in PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have some code that's extracting images out of PDF documents. I want to skip images that are too big, but I don't know how to find out an image is too big. I tried using `PdfImageXObject.getCOSObject().getLength()`, but in my test it appears to return a much bigger value than the image size on the file system.
How do I find out, at least approximately, how big the image is, in bytes, without actually extracting it (an expensive operation)?

Comment: I believe you are working in Java. If so, you should add that tag to your question.

Answer (score 3):

`getLength()` is not a good measure as it returns the encoded length of the stream. Depending on the encoding used in the PDF file, and the encoding you use on the file system, you'll end up with either a smaller or larger value.

- Image in the PDF uses JPEG encoding, you don't encode on saving the image: `getLength()` will be much smaller than the size on the filesystem.
- Image in the PDF is not encoded, you save as a JPEG image: your image on disk will be much smaller.

A more reliable way to do this would be to look at the width and height of the image which you can get from `PDImage`. This gives you the number of pixels horizontally and vertically. `PDImage` returns this using `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`.

This will not the exactly correct, if you want to total byte size of an image you would also have to look at the color space to see how many components per pixel (3 for RGB, 4 for CMYK for example) and how many bits per component in the image. But you can probably skip those values for the purpose you're looking at and just make due with the width and height to get a rough indication of whether you want to save this or not.

Comment: Isn't there going to be some compression/encoding when writing out the image as, let's say, JPEG to the file system? It seems that  `getWIdth() * getHeight() * C` won't account for the encoding reduction...

Comment: Remark where I said "and the encoding you use on the file system". So yes, of course that's also going to play a role. Your question was how to figure out - approximately - how big your images were - this you can accomplish with what I describe in my answer. It won't account for the encoding reduction on the file system, but that's impossible to predict (unless you can predict how well an image will compress and I think calculating that would take as much time as just extracting it so that defeats the purpose).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, my exact task is to filter out images that exceed a threshold after encoding reduction. So, I am filtering out anything over, say, 10MB after I extract  the bytes, but, since extraction of large images is expensive, I want a pre-filter. The pre-filter doesn't need to be exact, but I would like a rule like, "surely a 10000x10000 image would be too big extracted to bother extracting"